# How does the app run on sencha touch when deployed on device?

Tags: sencha-touch-2, cross-platform

I am developing an application using Sencha Touch. In order to run my application I have to run it in my tomcat server. But when the application is deployed on mobile,how does it run? Is there a server on mobile too ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have to run it in my tomcat server. But when the application is deployed on mobile,how does it run?**

It runs just like a native app without any server's aide for deployment. As stated in the above answer, your Sencha app runs on the Webkit instead of native platform as it is made of **Ext JS, HTML5, CSS/SASS**.

The reason why you require a local server when you are DEVELOPING is that it is merely mobile web pages as you are creating using web technologies. Hence, you will need a local environment to serve these pages. Later on, when you deploy the project, it gets converted as an application using a wrapper like PhoneGap.

Answer (score 2):

Sencha touch does not need a server to run, it is purely javascript/css/html. It can run in the native webview.

I usually deploy it in combination with phonegap/cordova so that i dont need a server at all, not even to serve the files. Of course assuming local storage on a device suffices.

check out this link for more info: 
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/native_packaging